# How does the browser find out the digital certificate of users?

Tags: paypal, certificate, ssl-certificate, payment, digital-certificate

some third payment website needs user to install the digital certificate for security,the website needs to know the user who you are,so the website will verify that the user is safe or not.
the question is that how does the browser find out the digital certificate of users?

Don't let the browser pop a window to select the certificate！！！

Some browser plugins of the payment website will take the correct certificate and to verify，then the browser will show a tip to tell the user “you are safe”..

if I need to develop a tool like that(Cross platforms,windows/OSX/Linux),what kind of language should I choose?What keyword should I use to search at Google?

Who can give me some infomation about that or some documentation...